# Change Mouse cursor according to X/Y position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there a simple cross-browser css3 solution to altering the mouse cursor to a clear right/ left graphic according to the mouse position  within a div?  Or is this a JQuery plugin job?

As in the mouse reaction in the carousel area in this http://themeforest.net/item/flamingo-agency-freelance-portfolio-theme/full_screen_preview/6077145

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [:hover selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp) with the [cursor property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp) to do this. Make two fixed, transparent elements for each half of the page to use with :hover, and specify a custom cursor image by assigning `cursor` a URL. No JS required...

Answer (score 0):

With JS programatically make a div follow the hidden cursor.
See example:

```
<div class="main_area">
...
...
...
</div>

<!--
// The html:
-->
<div id="custom_cursor">HELLO</div>

<!-- 
// The script uses jQuery
-->
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
          var $area = $('.main_area').css({
                     'cursor':'none'
               }),
          $myCursor = $('.custom_cursor').css({
                     'position': 'fixed',
                     'z-index': '999'
               })

          if ($myCursor.lenght){
           $area
               .on('mouseout.customCursor', function(){
                     $myCursor.hide()
               })
               .on('mousemove.customCursor', function(event){
                     $myCursor.show().css({
                       'left': event.clientX - 20,
                       'top': event.clientY + 7
                     })
               })
          }
     });
</script>
```